# Modificar idioma datepicker de Eureka

Tags: swift, datepicker

Tengo un datepicker creado para un formulario del pod de Eureka, pero el texto del datepicker está en inglés y necesitaría que estuviera en español, como puedo cambiar el idioma de datepicker de un formulario de Eureka?

> ```
> form +++ Section(header: "", footer: "")
>
>     <<< DateTimeRow(){
>         $0.title = "Fecha:"
>         $0.value = Date()
>       }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que editar la propiedad locale de tu date picker para asignarla al lenguaje que quieres ( En este caso español -> es):

```
let loc = Locale(identifier: "es")
self.datePicker.locale = loc
```

Comment: No se sirve, lo que tengo es un formulario Eureka y si pongo lo que tu me dices en load() o en el formulario sigue apareciendo en ingles, modifico la pregunta y pngo el código de Eureka

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la respuesta por si alguien le puede ayudar

```
<<< DateTimeRow(){
    $0.title = "Fecha:"
    $0.value = Date() }.cellSetup{ (cell, row) in
    row.cell.datePicker.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "es_ES") as Locale }
```